# single repeating command with input and output files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, command-line

I have been trying to learn how to adequately perform a single command multiple times using the command line. Although I have learned how to do a single command with no input and output files, it gets more complicated when it needs these.

The cp command requires this so lets use this as an example. I look for all images with .png extension and copy them. The way I have come up with after using google is:

```
find -regex ".*\.\(png\)" -exec cp {} {}3 \;
```

The only problem with that is that I have to rename the file with any figure after the name, so it gets renamed to something like file.png3 instead of file.png. I can't figure out how to do if differently as I can't put the new figure before the name as it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a better way to do this or am I going about it completely the wrong way?

Comment: You need to make it clearer exactly what you are trying to do, then we can give you some advice. If you want to apply an action to a list of files, a `for` loop is probably sufficient, e.g. `for f in *.png; do echo $(basename "$f" .png); done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you might do that in a single find command, but you could split it out. First, find the files with find. Then use sed to remove the .png extension. Finally, use xargs to run the copy function on each file. Like this:

```
find -regex ".*\.\(png\)" | sed -r 's/.png//g' | xargs -I {} cp {}.png {}_copy.png
```

If you didn't know, the pipe "|" will send the output of one program into the next.

Alternatively, you could just modify the beginning of the filename (so 3img.png instead of img.png3) or copy to a new folder.

Comment: very nice +1. didn't about it

Comment: this performs the action exactly how i asked. thanks.